# Get varied columns from in Entity Framework 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC solution.

I tried to get dynamic object and uncertainly column numbers and types from a stored procedure.

I prepared the stored procedure, but I couldn't find a solution about created stored procedure's class and more usage in EF Core 3.0.

I found a lot of solutions another versions of EF, but my developed project unfortunately business level project and already using EF Core 3.0 in many modules in a single a solution. How can I dynamically fetch data from SQL in ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core 3.0?

Comment: Use `Dapper` for such task.

Answer (score -1):

If your project is handling very large data transfers, I would not recommend using EntityFramework. You can take full control by using Repository Pattern. [take a look](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/repository-pattern-net-core/) here.

If you use Repository Pattern, it provides great advantages in terms of both program speed and change. That's why ORM is not the first product to look at in large projects.